# bing pars (KeyError: 'm')

Tags: python, parsing, bing

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import requests
#import re
#import sys
import os
import shutil
#import http.cookiejar
import json
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse

def get_soup(url, header):
    return BeautifulSoup(
        urllib.request.urlopen(
            urllib.request.Request(url,headers=header)),
        'html.parser')

def bing_image_search(query, countpage):
    query = urllib.parse.quote(query)
    query= query.split()
    query='+'.join(query)
    #add the directory for your image here
    #DIR=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "pictures")
    ActualImages=[]# contains the link for Large original images, type of  image
    for i in range(countpage):
        url="http://www.bing.com/images/search?q={}&pageNum={}&FORM=HDRSC2".format(query, i)
        print(url)
        header={'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"}
        soup = get_soup(url,header)
        for a in soup.find_all("a",{"class":"iusc"}):
            m = json.loads(a["m"])
            murl = m["murl"]
            turl = m["turl"]
            image_name = urllib.parse.urlsplit(murl).path.split("/")[-1]
            #ActualImages.append((image_name, turl, murl))
            ActualImages.append(turl)
    return ActualImages

results = bing_image_search("blouses", 1)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 results = bing_image_search("blouses", 1)
>
> 1 frames  in bing_image_search(query,
> countpage)
> 28         soup = get_soup(url,header)
> 29         for a in soup.find_all("a",{"class":"iusc"}):
> ---> 30             m = json.loads(a["m"])
> 31             murl = m["murl"]
> 32             turl = m["turl"]
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bs4/element.py in
> **getitem**(self, key)    1069         """tag[key] returns the value of the 'key' attribute for the tag,    1070         and throws an
> exception if it's not there."""
> -> 1071         return self.attrs[key]    1072     1073     def **iter**(self):
>
> KeyError: 'm'

Why does it process t-shirts normally but not blouses ?

I know that if you remove FORM=HDRSC2 from the query, everything works. Is it possible to make it work without removing this command ?

Answer (score 0):

Validate your inputs

```
if "m" not in a:
   continue
m = json.loads(a["m"])
```